# How to display foundation6 dropdown menu lists as inline-block or inline-table

Tags: css, list, menu, zurb-foundation-6

I have created a dropdown menu.I want the dropdown lists to display as inline-block or inline table but I can't figure out the right way foundation does it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div class="row column text-center">
<ul class="dropdown menu custom-menu" data-dropdown-menu>
<li>
  <a href="#">For Sale()</a>
  <ul class="menu">
  <!--I want the lists below to display horizontal as opposed to vertical-->
    <li><a href="#">Animals()</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Computer-Software()</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Computer-Hardware()</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cellphone-accessories()</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">For Babies-Infants()</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Used Cars()</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
  <li><a href="#">Vehicles</a>
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="">Used Cars</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sevices</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Personals</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't nest your ul.menus inside of a div>ul>li, can the sequential uls be divs? I haven't touched much foundation6

Comment: What do you suggest?